# Как правильно писать "иметь в виду" или "иметь ввиду"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Очень часто в интернете встречается разное написание "иметь ввиду" и "иметь в виду".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Существует тенденция в сращивании предлога со следующим словом и образованием наречия:

```
иметь вперемешку
иметь вплотную
иметь впереди
```

То же самое происходит и с

```
иметь ввиду
```

Однако **ввиду** не употребляется без **иметь** (**ввиду того что** это из другой оперы вообще). То есть нельзя назвать его автономным наречием а ля **впереди**. Поэтому правильно раздельное написание.

Answer (score 0):

"в виду" конечно. Иметь в чем? В виду (предложный падеж слова "вид").

Нет такого слова "ввида".